siunitx how to align decimals to thousands in tables to fit page format
Hi I'm facing an issue with siunitx where because of the page formatting imposed by the institution I cannot fit a table in the page.
This is because I have both values in the thousands range and very small decimals within the same column, so I wish to have those decimals (which I rounded to the 4th digit) aligned with the first digit of the thousand entries (in the tens of thousands range for some of the values).
For now, as some of these numbers are very small I omitted them; however, I wanted to know whether there is a workaround while preserving the nice siunitx formatting style.
Below a MWE, as an example I've replace the — for the rPAP with the corresponding value. Let me know, thanks in advance!
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcommand{\smallerbaseline}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

{\setlength\tabcolsep{.25pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt plus \textwidth}
\setlength\LTright{0pt plus \textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\smallerbaseline\bfseries} c 
        *{2}{S[table-format=5.4]
         S[table-format=5.4]
         S[table-format=-2.2,table-space-text-post=\unit{\percent}]<{\unit{\percent}}
         S[table-format=5.4]
         S[table-format=6.4]}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{APPROACH}} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{linear reference}  
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{pangenome graph} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \cmidrule{7-11}

& {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{R\textsuperscript{2}}} & \textit{minQ} & \textit{MaxQ} & {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{R\textsuperscript{2}}} & \textit{minQ} & \textit{MaxQ} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}

nAR & 2555 & 2527 & 86.30 & 2335 & 2902 & 2495 & 2432 & 86.30 & 2304 & 2886 \\
nAFR & 29247 & 29321 & 59.50 & 9338 & 48364 & 30250 & 30836 & 59.50 & 10086 & 47949 \\
nG1 & 21615 & 20035 & 6.47 & 1407 & 45583 & 20695 & 19127 & 6.47 & 1046 & 45266 \\
nG2 & 21615 & 19569 & 13.88 & 997 & 47504 & 21391 & 19116 & 13.88 & 803 & 46953 \\
nBE & 25837 & 26073 & -1.28 & 2284 & 47676 & 25644 & 25645 & -1.28 & 2244 & 47876 \\
nEUR & 18824 & 12674 & 38.45 & 2117 & 45728 & 18574 & 12452 & 38.45 & 1789 & 44654 \\
nCEA & 30985 & 31087 & 49.41 & 11954 & 48772 & 28813 & 29113 & 49.41 & 9025 & 47363 \\
nPAP & 13278 & 10605 & 60.58 & 3712 & 35011 & 14031 & 10917 & 60.58 & 4121 & 35112 \\
nAFR-G1/BE/G2 & 27808 & 26002 & 93.57 & 17564 & 43458 & 25815 & 23931 & 93.57 & 16429 & 41473 \\
nN-NR & 2194 & 2151 & 94.50 & 1898 & 2706 & 2495 & 2429 & 94.50 & 2027 & 2901 \\
nD-D1/2 & 22918 & 19979 & 35.39 & 2513 & 48300 & 25192 & 24594 & 35.39 & 2731 & 48524 \\
nD-N & 17098 & 12169 & 43.85 & 2918 & 43354 & 16834 & 12423 & 43.85 & 2885 & 41932 \\
nAR-D-N & 19197 & 16445 & 22.00 & 1924 & 45600 & 18903 & 16445 & 22.00 & 1890 & 44981 \\
nAR-M & 23054 & 23128 & 99.80 & 19655 & 26341 & 19148 & 18975 & 99.80 & 16653 & 22435 \\
rPAP & 0.0170 & {\textemdash} & 10.55 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 10.55 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
rEUR-CEA & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 5.76 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 5.76 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
tdAFR-G1 & 97428 & 96736 & 50.95 & 56437 & 139325 & 94479 & 91173 & 50.95 & 55451 & 137513 \\
tdAFR-G2 & 94122 & 90719 & 50.93 & 55657 & 138184 & 95821 & 91886 & 50.93 & 56422 & 138758 \\
tdOA1 & 62685 & 57826 & 46.18 & 45729 & 96452 & 58110 & 54272 & 46.18 & 45663 & 90268 \\
tOAbot1 & 60630 & 54566 & 46.09 & 43497 & 93941 & 55656 & 51883 & 46.09 & 42971 & 85418 \\
tdOA2 & 49041 & 46917 & 24.25 & 40837 & 63729 & 47796 & 46030 & 24.25 & 40525 & 60121 \\
tOAbot2 & 46734 & 44773 & 24.22 & 37999 & 62973 & 45749 & 43668 & 24.22 & 37920 & 59744 \\
tdG2-BE & 73268 & 66597 & 22.40 & 50387 & 117577 & 72338 & 65073 & 22.40 & 50455 & 111864 \\
tdEUR-CEA & 38696 & 37550 & 11.25 & 30900 & 52793 & 37609 & 36408 & 11.25 & 30728 & 49491 \\
taD2-CEA & 30035 & 28725 & 1.79 & 20541 & 45124 & 29038 & 27876 & 1.79 & 20859 & 40769 \\
paD2-CEA & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.23 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.23 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
taBE-EUR & 24468 & 23277 & 0.87 & 11001 & 43495 & 24042 & 23406 & 0.87 & 11101 & 39080 \\
paBE-EUR & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.18 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.18 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
taD1-PAP & 44550 & 43098 & 17.72 & 31204 & 65179 & 43254 & 41473 & 17.72 & 31478 & 62175 \\
paD1-PAP & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.22 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.22 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
taAR-PAP & 52415 & 49013 & 33.25 & 37303 & 80960 & 49523 & 46828 & 33.25 & 36939 & 71169 \\
paAR-PAP & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.19 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.19 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
taN-EUR-CEA & 42778 & 40926 & 18.74 & 33088 & 56748 & 41427 & 39956 & 18.74 & 33298 & 55674 \\
paN-EUR-CEA & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.23 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.23 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
taN-G2 & 52918 & 50734 & 30.19 & 43033 & 71761 & 51816 & 49771 & 30.19 & 42818 & 68086 \\
paN-G2 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.13 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -1.13 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m78 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 17.87 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 17.87 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m87 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -0.75 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -0.75 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m810 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 3.59 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 3.59 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m108 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 4.04 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 4.04 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1011 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -0.19 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -0.19 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1110 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 26.86 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 26.86 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1112 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 18.87 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 18.87 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1211 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 21.04 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 21.04 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1213 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 36.13 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 36.13 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1312 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 40.14 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 40.14 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1\textunderscore1011 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -0.99 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & -0.99 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1\textunderscore1110 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 1.39 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 1.39 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1\textunderscore1113 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 1.39 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 1.39 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
m1\textunderscore1311 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 0.72 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} & 0.72 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}


My impression is that roughly two thirds of the table's rows contain numbers whose structure conforms to the stated layout (e.g., 29247), whereas one third of the rows need to be typeset according to a very different layout (e.g., 0.0170). Is this impression correct?

@Mico yes, indeed. Sorry if I haven't been more accurate, I mostly wanted to indicate that this affects all columns but the correlation one.

I suggest you create two longtable environments, with the same overall layout except for how many integer and decimal digits should be displayed: Mainly S[table-format=5.0] in the first table, and mainly S[table-format=1.4] in the second. I use the qualifier "mainly" because of the $R^2$ columns, which would appear to be formatted the same in both tables.
I must admit to seeing no need for bold-facing the material in the left-hand text columns.

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}

\providecommand\tnd{{--}} % handy shortcut macro
\providecommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next few instructions
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}

\begin{longtable}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l  
        *{2}{S[table-format= 5.0]
             S[table-format= 5.0]
             S[table-format=-1.2, table-space-text-post=\%]<{\%}
             S[table-format= 5.0]
             S[table-format= 6.0]}
}

%% headers and footers

\toprule
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{Approach} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Linear reference}  
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Pangenome graph} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \cmidrule{7-11}
& {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \mc{$R^2$} & {\textit{MinQ}} & {\textit{MaxQ}} 
& {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \mc{$R^2$} & {\textit{MinQ}} & {\textit{MaxQ}} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{11}{r}{(table continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of table

nAR & 2555 & 2527 & 86.30 & 2335 & 2902 & 2495 & 2432 & 86.30 & 2304 & 2886 \\
nAFR & 29247 & 29321 & 59.50 & 9338 & 48364 & 30250 & 30836 & 59.50 & 10086 & 47949 \\
nG1 & 21615 & 20035 & 6.47 & 1407 & 45583 & 20695 & 19127 & 6.47 & 1046 & 45266 \\
nG2 & 21615 & 19569 & 13.88 & 997 & 47504 & 21391 & 19116 & 13.88 & 803 & 46953 \\
nBE & 25837 & 26073 & -1.28 & 2284 & 47676 & 25644 & 25645 & -1.28 & 2244 & 47876 \\
nEUR & 18824 & 12674 & 38.45 & 2117 & 45728 & 18574 & 12452 & 38.45 & 1789 & 44654 \\
nCEA & 30985 & 31087 & 49.41 & 11954 & 48772 & 28813 & 29113 & 49.41 & 9025 & 47363 \\
nPAP & 13278 & 10605 & 60.58 & 3712 & 35011 & 14031 & 10917 & 60.58 & 4121 & 35112 \\
nAFR-G1/BE/G2 & 27808 & 26002 & 93.57 & 17564 & 43458 & 25815 & 23931 & 93.57 & 16429 & 41473 \\
nN-NR & 2194 & 2151 & 94.50 & 1898 & 2706 & 2495 & 2429 & 94.50 & 2027 & 2901 \\
nD-D1/2 & 22918 & 19979 & 35.39 & 2513 & 48300 & 25192 & 24594 & 35.39 & 2731 & 48524 \\
nD-N & 17098 & 12169 & 43.85 & 2918 & 43354 & 16834 & 12423 & 43.85 & 2885 & 41932 \\
nAR-D-N & 19197 & 16445 & 22.00 & 1924 & 45600 & 18903 & 16445 & 22.00 & 1890 & 44981 \\
nAR-M & 23054 & 23128 & 99.80 & 19655 & 26341 & 19148 & 18975 & 99.80 & 16653 & 22435 \\
tdAFR-G1 & 97428 & 96736 & 50.95 & 56437 & 139325 & 94479 & 91173 & 50.95 & 55451 & 137513 \\
tdAFR-G2 & 94122 & 90719 & 50.93 & 55657 & 138184 & 95821 & 91886 & 50.93 & 56422 & 138758 \\
tdOA1 & 62685 & 57826 & 46.18 & 45729 & 96452 & 58110 & 54272 & 46.18 & 45663 & 90268 \\
tOAbot1 & 60630 & 54566 & 46.09 & 43497 & 93941 & 55656 & 51883 & 46.09 & 42971 & 85418 \\
tdOA2 & 49041 & 46917 & 24.25 & 40837 & 63729 & 47796 & 46030 & 24.25 & 40525 & 60121 \\
tOAbot2 & 46734 & 44773 & 24.22 & 37999 & 62973 & 45749 & 43668 & 24.22 & 37920 & 59744 \\
tdG2-BE & 73268 & 66597 & 22.40 & 50387 & 117577 & 72338 & 65073 & 22.40 & 50455 & 111864 \\
tdEUR-CEA & 38696 & 37550 & 11.25 & 30900 & 52793 & 37609 & 36408 & 11.25 & 30728 & 49491 \\
taD2-CEA & 30035 & 28725 & 1.79 & 20541 & 45124 & 29038 & 27876 & 1.79 & 20859 & 40769 \\
taBE-EUR & 24468 & 23277 & 0.87 & 11001 & 43495 & 24042 & 23406 & 0.87 & 11101 & 39080 \\
taD1-PAP & 44550 & 43098 & 17.72 & 31204 & 65179 & 43254 & 41473 & 17.72 & 31478 & 62175 \\
taAR-PAP & 52415 & 49013 & 33.25 & 37303 & 80960 & 49523 & 46828 & 33.25 & 36939 & 71169 \\
taN-EUR-CEA & 42778 & 40926 & 18.74 & 33088 & 56748 & 41427 & 39956 & 18.74 & 33298 & 55674 \\
taN-G2 & 52918 & 50734 & 30.19 & 43033 & 71761 & 51816 & 49771 & 30.19 & 42818 & 68086 \\

\end{longtable}



%% second longtable: same overall layout, but different number formatting
\sisetup{group-digits=none}
\begin{longtable}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l  
        *{2}{S[table-format= 1.4]
             S[table-format= 1.4]
             S[table-format=-1.2, table-space-text-post=\%]<{\%}
             S[table-format= 1.4]
             S[table-format= 1.4]}
}

%% headers and footers

\toprule
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{Approach} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Linear reference}  
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Pangenome graph} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \cmidrule{7-11}
& {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \mc{$R^2$} & {\textit{MinQ}} & {\textit{MaxQ}} 
& {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \mc{$R^2$} & {\textit{MinQ}} & {\textit{MaxQ}} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{11}{l}{(table continued from preceding page)}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{11}{r}{(table continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table

rPAP     & 0.0170 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
rEUR-CEA & 0.0170 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
paD2-CEA & 0.0170 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
paBE-EUR & \tnd & \tnd & -1.18 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -1.18 & \tnd & \tnd \\
paD1-PAP & \tnd & \tnd & -1.22 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -1.22 & \tnd & \tnd \\
paAR-PAP & \tnd & \tnd & -1.19 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -1.19 & \tnd & \tnd \\
paN-EUR-CEA & \tnd & \tnd & -1.23 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -1.23 & \tnd & \tnd \\
paN-G2 & \tnd & \tnd & -1.13 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -1.13 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m78 & \tnd & \tnd & 17.87 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 17.87 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m87 & \tnd & \tnd & -0.75 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -0.75 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m810 & \tnd & \tnd & 3.59 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 3.59 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m108 & \tnd & \tnd & 4.04 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 4.04 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1011 & \tnd & \tnd & -0.19 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -0.19 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1110 & \tnd & \tnd & 26.86 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 26.86 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1112 & \tnd & \tnd & 18.87 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 18.87 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1211 & \tnd & \tnd & 21.04 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 21.04 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1213 & \tnd & \tnd & 36.13 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 36.13 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1312 & \tnd & \tnd & 40.14 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 40.14 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1\_1011 & \tnd & \tnd & -0.99 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & -0.99 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1\_1110 & \tnd & \tnd & 1.39 & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & \tnd & 1.39 & \tnd & \tnd \\
m1\_1113 & 0.0170 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
m1\_1311 & 0.0170 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 10.55 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}


thanks a lot for the suggestions! Also, thanks for the second opinion on the left-hand column. By any chance, since I was discussing this with my supervisor, would there be the chance to have scientific notation only for the decimals in the table, or this would require to have a second table too. Let me know, thanks!

@Matteo - Please clarify what you mean by "scientific notation". (E.g., something like "1.53E-4"?) And, would these numbers occur just in the second table?

yes, exactly. If worth, it might be useful to represent them as 10 power negative exponent. However, my question is also whether the two things (e.g. very big numbers and very small numbers in scientific notation) can co-exist in the same column. Of course, without colliding with page formatting so that the table can nicely fit in the page.

@Matteo - The siunitx package can indeed display integers and decimal numbers in scientific notation. Please study section 4.4, "Post-processing numbers", of the user guide of the siunitx package for more information on this subject. (To open a copy of this user guide in a pdf browser, just open a command window and type texdoc siunitx.) Please also consider posting a new query on this site.

thanks again! I've made some experiments and this solution seems to be working best. I see how it goes and in case I'll open a new query specific to have everything in one table.
